# Eigenvalue problem of $L_z$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wavefunction, complex-numbers, eigenvalue

From Shankar's QM book pg. 313, the eigenvalue problem for $L_z=XP_y-YP_x$ in polar coordinates is
$$-i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi(\rho,\phi)}{\partial \phi}=l_z\psi(\rho,\phi)$$
since $L_z=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ in polar coordinates.

The solution to this equation is $$\psi=R(\rho)e^{i l_z\phi/\hbar}$$

It was then said that $l_z$ seems to be arbitrary: it can be complex since $\phi$ goes only from $0$ to $2\pi$. This can be compared to the eigenfunctions $e^{ipx/\hbar}$ of momentum, where we could argue that $p$ had to be real to keep $|\psi|$ bounded as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$.

I don't understand why $l_z$ can be complex while $p$ has to be real. How can it be shown explicitly that this is so?

Taking the momentum eigenfunciton for example, does he mean that $|e^{ipx/\hbar}| \rightarrow0$ as $|x| \rightarrow\infty$ when $p$ is real? That is not the case as $|e^{ip\infty/\hbar}|=1$.

Comment: In general the eigenvalues of an operator can be complex unless we can find a reason why they cannot be. The argument used for why the momentum eigenvalues must be real does not work here because that argument depended on the limit $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$. But $\phi$ does not go to infinity, so this won't work. Having said that I would strongly suggest you carry on reading. I don't have a copy of Shankar on hand but I strongly suspect you have stopped part way through his argument

Comment: @BySymmetry That's all he said in the text. I can see the idea behind his argument but I don't know how to show it mathematically.

Comment: Actually, if $\psi$ is a globally well-defined function, it must be $2\pi$ periodic in $\phi$, so $l_z=\hbar m$ with $m$ an integer.

Comment: In the case of $p$, the reason why the spectrum is real is more subtle since it does not rigorously coincide with the eigenvalues of the operator. You'll need functional analysis to define things properly.

Comment: If you plugg in a complex value for p, you convert the complex exponential function to an ordinary exponential function....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From Shankar's QM book pg. 313...
> $$-i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi(\rho,\phi)}{\partial \phi}=l_z\psi(\rho,\phi)$$

> The solution to this equation is $$\psi=R(\rho)e^{i l_z\phi/\hbar}$$

I'm going to drop the $\rho$ dependence and consider a related problem.

Consider the solution to the differential equation:
$$
\frac{df}{d\phi} = \alpha f
$$
The solution is:
$$
f(\phi) = Ae^{\alpha \phi}\;,
$$
where $A$ is a constant determined by the boundary condition.

The constant $\alpha$ could be real, or imaginary, or generally, complex. The constant $\alpha$ is part of the problem statement, we do not determine it. If $\alpha$ happens to be purely imaginary, we get wave solutions. If it happens to be purely real, we get exponentially growing or decaying solutions. If it is complex, we get a combination of both.

For our original problem, the constant $\alpha = i\hbar \ell_z$, but this does not, a priori, tell us anything about $\ell_z$.

For more information about how we can determine more about $\ell_z$ given some additional structure, see the "update" section below. But, if all we have is the differential equation, it can be solved generally for complex $\alpha$ and there's no reason *a priori* to force $\alpha$ to be real.

> It was then said that $l_z$ seems to be arbitrary: it can be complex since $\phi$ goes only from $0$ to $2\pi$. This can be compared to the eigenfunctions $e^{ipx/\hbar}$ of momentum, where we could argue that $p$ had to be real to keep $|\psi|$ **bounded** as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$. (Emphasis added.)

Note the word "bounded" in the above quote.

> I don't understand why $l_z$ can be complex while $p$ has to be real. How can it be shown explicitly that this is so?

The author is saying $\ell_z$ *can be* considered complex at this point. As yet, the author has provided no reason why it should not be complex.

> Taking the momentum eigenfunciton for example, does he mean that $|e^{ipx/\hbar}| \rightarrow0$ as $|x| \rightarrow\infty$ when $p$ is real?

No. The author wrote "bounded" not "goes to zero."

But, you see that if $p$ was imaginary the solution would blow up at either positive or negative infinity, since it would be an exponential. So the function $e^{ipx/\hbar}$ would not be *bounded* if $p$ was complex with an imaginary part.

> That is not the case as $|e^{ip\infty/\hbar}|=1$.

Correct. The author wrote "bounded." For real $p$ the function $e^{ipx/\hbar}$ is bounded by $1$ for all $x$.

---

**Update**: Not sure if OP is interested in more information on why $\ell_z$ is integral in practice in quantum mechanics when it stands for an orbital angular momentum quantum number... But, if so, I added more info on the conventional values of $\ell_z$.

First, if you would like to see why, $\ell_z$ is real, you can use the fact that we are working with a normalized vector space in quantum mechanics, where, for example, we define:
$$
<g|f> = \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi g^*(\phi)f(\phi)
$$

We have:
$$
\ell_z = <f|L_z|f> = -i\hbar\int d\phi f^*\frac{df}{d\phi}
$$
and so:
$$
\ell_z^* = +i\hbar\int d\phi f \frac{df^*}{d\phi} = {\left. i\hbar|f|^2\right|}^{2\pi}_{0}-i\hbar\int d\phi f^* \frac{df}{d\phi} = {\left. i\hbar|f|^2\right|}^{2\pi}_{0}+\ell_z\;,
$$
where the second to last equality comes from integration by parts and the last comes from the definition of $\ell_z$.

If we further assume that the *intensity* (the probability density in quantum mechanics) is singly valued as a function of $\phi$ then $|f|^2$ has the same value at $0$ and $2\pi$ and then putting this all together tells us that:
$$
\ell_z^* = \ell_z\;,
$$
which means $\ell_z$ is real.

If you further assume that the wavefunction $f$ is also single valued for any value of $\phi$ (which makes sense when $\phi$ is the azimuthal variable in a 3d coordinate system) then clearly $\ell_z$ has to take on integral values.

Of course, it is not true in general that angular momenta have integer eigenvalues, since we know some wavefunctions have half-integer angular momentum... but that is beyond the scope of this question and is discussed elsewhere (including on this very site).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to point out that $l_z$ *must* be real for a very fundamental reason: eigenvalues of Hermitian operators must be real. Let me prove this very quickly. I'll not use the Dirac formalism since I'm not sure you are familiar with it. Let ${\cal H}$ be a Hilbert space with inner product $(,)$. Let $A$ be a Hermitian operator. Then the adjoint $A^\dagger$ is defined by $$(\psi,A\phi)=(A^\dagger \psi,\phi)\tag{1}.$$

Consider now the eigenvalue equation $$A\psi=\lambda \psi\tag{2}.$$

Observe that if we take the inner product with $\psi$ we have $$(\psi,A\psi)=\lambda (\psi,\psi)\Longrightarrow \lambda = \dfrac{(\psi,A\psi)}{(\psi,\psi)}\tag{3}.$$

Now take the complex conjugate. We know that $(\psi,\psi)$ is real since it is the norm of a vector. On the other hand $$(\psi,A\psi)^\ast = (A\psi,\psi)=(A^\dagger \psi,\psi)=(\psi,A\psi)\tag{4}$$ where in the second equality we used that $A$ is Hermitian, namely, $A=A^\dagger$, and in the last equality we used the definition of the adjoint. It follows that $(\psi,A\psi)$ is also real. As a consequence $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$.

So, since $L_z$ is Hermitian (this is manifest from its definition in terms of position and momentum), and since your equation is exactly $L_z\psi=l_z\psi$ the general result just proven implies that we must necessarily have $l_z\in \mathbb{R}$.

Nevertheless, let us pretend we don't know any of this and let us analyze things from the point of view you present. The eigenvalue equation for $L_z$ determines only the angular dependence of $\psi$. As you point out $\psi(\rho,\phi)=R(\rho)e^{i l_z\phi/\hbar}$. Since $\phi\in [0,2\pi]$ even if $l_z$ were to have a non-zero imaginary part, this would not interfere in $\psi$ being normalizable. I think this is all the author is saying, but I feel it is a somewhat irrelevant point to make: $l_z$ *must* be real because it is an eigenvalue of a Hermitian operator, so what is the point in debating that something suggests it could be complex?

Moreover, if $\psi(\rho,\phi)$ is assumed to be a well-defined function on the plane, it must be $2\pi$-periodic in $\phi$. The reason is that the coordinates $\phi$ and $\phi+2\pi$ label the exact same physical point. This already demands that $l_z = m\hbar$ where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, ruling out any possible imaginary part, consistent with the general argument.

Comment: agree with you. I guess that everyone here agrees. Looks like a question with very easy and fast answer: 99% is so, let's leave 1% of uncertainty we didn't understand the question or other particular details

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read Shankar, but it seems to me that if you are looking for functions $\psi(\rho, \phi) = R(\rho) e^{i l_z \phi / \hbar}$ that are continuous and smooth at every point in space, it must be $2\pi/\,n$-periodic (with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$) w.r.t. to the azimuthal angle $\phi$, and thus

$\dfrac{l_z}{\hbar} = n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

And honestly, I see no reason for a problem in free space, with no "external" forcing/constraints, to have a solution with discontinuity at a specific value of the angle $\phi$, only. Why at that value? What happens if I choose another direction as the direction of $\phi = 0$? Does my physical process really depend on the coordinates I use to describe it?

Answer (score 1):

I'll write what other people have written but in a slightly different way. Let's start at the beginning with the eigenvalue problem $L_z\psi=\ell_z\psi$. As you stated, in polar coordinates, this is the problem
$$-i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi(\rho,\phi)}{\partial\phi}=\ell_z\psi(\rho,\phi).
$$
Taking a separation of variables Ansatz $\psi(\rho,\phi)=R(\rho)\Phi(\phi)$, you can see the only restriction is
$$
-i\hbar\frac{\partial\Phi(\phi)}{\partial\phi}=\ell_z\Phi(\phi).
$$
From a purely mathematical point of view, the solution of this equation looks the same independent of whether $\ell_z\in\mathbb{R}$ or $\ell_z\in\mathbb{C}$. In both cases, one writes the solution $\Phi(\phi)=\Phi(0)e^{i\frac{\ell_z}{\hbar}\phi}$. Splitting as $\ell_z=m+ik$, this would read instead as
$$\Phi(\phi)=\Phi(0)e^{i\frac{m}{\hbar}\phi-\frac{k}{\hbar}\phi}.$$

So far, this has followed purely from mathematical considerations. Since $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, this function is well-behaved and *bounded*. Bounded, as noted by hft, is not the same as *goes to zero*. The point is that as $\phi$ goes through its range of values, $\Phi(\phi)$ does not diverge.

**Examples:**
If $\phi\geq0$ were the restriction, then we would require that $k>0$. In this case, then $\Phi(\phi)$ is bounded above by its value $|\Phi(0)|$ since for $\phi>0$, you can see that $|\Phi(\phi)|<|\Phi(0)|$. If $k<0$, there wouldn't exist such a bound. Or, as in the momentum case, if $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$, then any non-zero value for $k$ would cause a divergence in the full range of $\phi$, hence, as you noted, $k=0$ and so $\ell_z\in \mathbb{R}$, it would be purely real.

Now, by adding the physical point of view - that observables are hermitian operators and therefore have real eigenvalues - we find the first restriction on $\ell_z$, that $\ell_z$ must be real and not complex. And, as Shankar shows on page $314$, this is equivalent to $\Phi(0)=\Phi(2\pi)$. Concretely, this means
$$
\Phi(0)=\Phi(0)e^{i\frac{\ell_z}{\hbar}2\pi},
$$which is the requirement that $\ell_z/\hbar \in \mathbb{Z}$, and so, in the terminology of Shankar, it is an integral multiple of $\hbar$, $\ell_z=m\hbar$.

However, we did not need the hermicity of $L_z$ to realise that $\ell_z\in\mathbb{R}$ and that it must be an integral multiple of $\hbar$. To avoid a multi-valued function on the plane must, it must be $2\pi$-periodic. This alone informs us that $\Phi(\phi+2\pi)=\Phi(\phi)$ and so in particular this holds for $\phi=0$ and $\Phi(0)=\Phi(0)e^{i\frac{\ell_z}{\hbar}2\pi}$, which again implies $\ell_z=m\hbar$.

One might circumvent this by strictly demanding $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$, however the hermicity again requires the restriction.